# Is it possible that I could find a row contains a string? Assume that I do not know which columns contain a string

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, relational-database

I know that there are several ways to find which row's column contains a string, like using [column name] regexp ' ' or [column name] like ' '

while currently what I need some help is I have a table with several columns, all of there are varchar or text and I am not sure which column contains a certain string. Just say that I want to search a "xxx from a table. Several different columns could contain this string or not. Is there a way that I could find which column contains this string?

I have a thinking and the solution could be

```
 select * from [table name] where [column1] regexp 'xxx' or 
    [column2] regexp 'xxx' or ...... [column39] regexp 'xxx' or .....
[colum60] regexp 'xxx' or ... or [column 80] regexp 'xxx';
```

I do not want the query like this. Is there another effective way?

To give a better example, say that we are searching for a table that belongs to a blog.

We have title, URL, content, key words, tag, comment and so on. Now we just say, if any blog article is related to "database-normalization", this word may appear in the title, URL or content or anywhere, and I do not want to write it one by one like

```
where title regexp 'database-normalization' or content regexp 'database-normalization' or url regexp 'database-normalization'......
```

as when there are hundreds columns, I need to write a hundred, or in this case is there an effective way instead of write hundred or statement? Like using if-else or collections or some others to build the query.

Comment: BTW, `regexp` is not [sargable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sargable) and will force a full table scan (linear traversal through all rows), which will not scale well with the number of rows. Your main problem, it seems to me, is not about writing tedious SQL, it's about extracting acceptable performance for non-trivial number of rows, _while_ searching in the middle of fields. If that's the case, you should take a look at full-text indexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a pure dynamic way, you can try this. I've tried it long back on `sql-server` and hope it may help you.

```
#TMP_TABLE -- a temporary  table
- PK, IDENTITY
- TABLE_NAME
- COLUMN_NAME
- IS_EXIST


INSERT INTO #TMP_TABLE (TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME)
SELECT C.TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = <your-table> AND C.DATA_TYPE = 'varchar'; -- you can modify it to handle multiple table at once.

-- boundaries
SET @MINID = (SELECT ISNULL(MIN(<PK>),0) FROM #TMP_TABLE ); 
SET @MAXID = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(<PK>),0) FROM #TMP_TABLE );

WHILE ((@MINID<=@MAXID) AND (@MINID<>0))
BEGIN
    SELECT @TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME,@COLUMN_NAME =  COLUMN_NAME
    FROM  #TMP_TABLE 
    WHERE <PK> = @MINID;

    SET @sqlString =  ' UPDATE #TMP_TABLE 
                    SET IS_EXIST = 1 
                    WHERE EXIST (SELECT 1 FROM '+ @TABLE_NAME+' WHERE  '+ @COLUMN_NAME +' = ''demo.webstater.com'') AND <PK> = '+ @MINID;
    EXEC(@sql) ;
    SET @MINID = (SELECT MIN(<PK>) FROM #TMP_TABLE WHERE <PK> > @MINID );
END 

SELECT * FROM #TMP_TABLE WHERE IS_EXIST = 1 ; -- will give you matched results.
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I have read it and transferred it into mysql format. From your code I have understand how to build the similar query.

Comment: I'm glad I helped

Answer (score 1):

If you know the columns in advance, what you proposed is probably the most effective way (if a little verbose).

Otherwise, you could get the column names from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS and construct dynamic SQL based on that.

Comment: Yes, my possible answer is based on that I know the column. Say if we have a table, that contains 50 columns, and 40 of them, each is a varchar or text and may contain this string. In this case, if I write [column A] regexp 'xxx' or [column B] regexp 'xxx' .... and then I need to write 39 of or... I think there could be a more effective way to do this... thus why I am coming to ask...

Comment: @spartaslave The point of INFORMATION_SCHEMA is that you don't have to write the SQL yourself - you can make a program that writes it for you. Whether it's worth spending the time to write that program, as opposed to just writing the SQL manually, is a different matter...

Answer (score 1):

His question is not to query specific columns with like clause. He has been asking to apply same pattern across columns **dynamically**.

**Example:** Table having 3 columns - FirstName, LastName, Address and pattern matching is "starts with A" then resulting query should be:
Select * From Customer where FirstName like 'A%" or LastName like 'A%" or Address like 'A%'

If you want to build query in business layer, this could easily be done with reflection along with EF.

If you are motivated to do in database then you can achieve by building query dynamically and then execute through sp_executesql.

Comment: Yes, but what I want to know is that is there a better way to write the query, say if I have 40 columns, all may contain the string.. And umm, in this case do I need to write a query using 39 'or' s to connect, or I could use some other method?

Comment: If you're getting to 40 columns where you need to do this, you perhaps should ask whether there's a better way of organising the data (e.g. one table with key-value pairs) or look at any free-text-search facility your database might offer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (Just pass tablename and the string to be find)-:

```
create proc usp_findString 
@tablename varchar(500),
@string varchar(max)
as
Begin

Declare @sql2 varchar(max),@sql nvarchar(max)
SELECT @sql2=
STUFF((SELECT ', case when '+QUOTENAME(NAME)+'='''+@string+''' then 1 else 0 end as '+NAME
FROM (select a.name from sys.columns a join sys.tables b on a.[object_id]=b.[object_id] where b.name=@tablename) T1
--WHERE T1.ID=T2.ID
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
--print @string
set @sql='select '+@sql2+' from '+@tablename
print @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sql

End
```

SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `CASE` to check the substring existence with `LOCATE` in mysql and return the column but all you have to check in every column of the table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE test(col1 VARCHAR(1000), col2 VARCHAR(1000), col3 VARCHAR(1000))
INSERT INTO test VALUES
('while currently what I need some help is I have a table with 10 columns',
'contains a certain string. Just say that I want to search a table',
'contains a certain string demo.webstater.com')

SELECT (CASE WHEN LOCATE('demo.webstater.com', col1, 1) > 0 THEN 'col1'
        WHEN LOCATE('demo.webstater.com', col2, 1) > 0 THEN 'col2'
        WHEN LOCATE('demo.webstater.com', col3, 1) > 0 THEN 'col3'  
    END) whichColumn
FROM test
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
whichColumn
col3
```

Answer (score -2):

There are many ways in which you can do your analysis. You can use "LIKE A%%" if it starts from A in SQL, "REGEX" LibrarY for multiple checks.

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you said, but this is still just based on the specific column. Let's say you have column A, B, C, D, E, each column could contain the string or not, but once it contains, I want to get this row, no matter which column contains.